# How to use useNavigate( ) React-Router-Dom Hook in Class Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

**How to use useNavigate( ) React-Router-Dom Hook in Class Component ?**

```
export default class MovieForm extends Form {
  state = {
    data : {},
    error : {},
  }
  onSubmit(){
    // Navigate to Another Component
  }
  render(){
  // rendering the Form UI
  }
}
```

I want to Navigate to Another Component on Submitting the Form.

Official React-Router-Dom Documentation Says I can use 'useNavigate( )' Hook only inside a Functional Component.

I have a class Component and I can't make it functional Component. because It extends the Form Class and I want all the Functionality of Form Class in this MovieForm Component.

So how can I Navigate to Another Component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since React router v6, you can use a [Navigate](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/navigate) component.

```js
export default class MovieForm extends Form {
  state = {
    data : {},
    error : {},
    submitted : false,
  }
  onSubmit(){
    // Navigate to Another Component
    this.setState({submitted: true});
  }
  render(){
      // rendering the Form UI
      {submitted && 
        <Navigate to={// Router path to the target component} 
                  state={// you can pass state/props here}
        />
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use the `useNavigate` hook then you have two choices basically.

1. Convert class-based components into React function components and use the `useNavigate` hook.
2. Create a custom `withRouter` Higher Order Component since `react-router-dom@6` no longer exports one.

I won't cover the conversion case. Here's a `withRouter` HOC implementation.

Example:

```
import { useNavigate, /* other hooks */ } from 'react-router-dom'; 

const withRouter = WrappedComponent => props => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  // other hooks

  return (
    <WrappedComponent
      {...props}
      {...{ navigate, /* other hooks */ }}
    />
  );
};

export default withRouter;
```

Now you import `withRouter` and decorate the class component so that `navigate` and any other RRD hook values are injected as props.

```
...
import withRouter from '../path/to/withRouter';

class MovieForm extends React.Component { // *
  state = {
    data : {},
    error : {},
  }

  onSubmit() {
    const { navigate } = this.props;
    // Navigate to Another Component
    navigate("...target path...");
  }

  render() {
    // rendering the Form UI
  }
}

export default withRouter(MovieForm);
```

**** React components should only extend `React.Component`, not other custom Javascript classes! See [Composition vs Inheritance](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html)***

Comment: this works but navigate doesnt work when used inside componentdidmount or constructor on page mount, any thoughts on this ? it works on button clicks

I am doing migration from v5 to v6, so im on "react-router-dom-v5-compat": "^6.21.1"

Comment: @ShamseerAhammed You shouldn't have any side-effects in the constructor, otherwise I believe it *should* work in `componentDidMount`. Do you have a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo handy for a reproducible example? I'll explore this a bit. I've not used the compat library so I'm not actually familiar with what exactly it fills the gaps of. Other than that, React class components are effectively deprecated, so you should probably try converting to React function components and use the hooks directly.

Comment: @ShamseerAhammed Here's a quick [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-use-usenavigate-react-router-dom-hook-in-class-component-jqzcs7) I threw together and the navigation works from `componentDidMount` as I'd suspected it would. If you've a more specific issue you are trying to work through and resolve feel free to create a new post on SO and ping me here in a comment a link to it and I can take a look when available.